# Null pointer exception when trying to access method (java)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am developing some code in Java but facing a problem with a NPE. 
It happens when I try to use a method in another class. 
Here is my code :

```
public class MyClass{

    private Attributes attr = null;

public static void main(String [ ] args) throws ParseException, SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
         MyClass main = new MyClass();
         Options options = main.parseCommandLine();

        CommandLineParser parser = new BasicParser();
        CommandLine cl = parser.parse(options, args);
        main.configureAttributes(main);
    }

private void configureAttributes(MyClass main, CommandLine cl) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {         
        String[] attributes = cl.getOptionValues("a");
        Integer tag = null;

        for(int i = 0; i < attributes.length ; i++) {
            String[] parts = attributes[i].split("=");
            String tagName = parts[0];
            String value = parts[1]; 
            tag = Integer.parseInt(tagName,16);                             
            this.attr.setString(tag, DICT.vrOf(tag), value);
        }
    }           
}
```

But I am getting an NPE on the last line : this.attr.setString(tag, DICT.vrOf(tag), value);

I have all the right imports. It is a Maven project so I also added the dependency to my pom.xml.

Thanks a lot for your help !

V.

Comment: you can't call a a method on null and `this.attr` is null. you should initialize it before you call `setString`

Comment: Stupid me, of course ! Thanks for your answer hotfix !

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to initialize your `attr` field. According to your source here is only one assignment to this field: `private Attributes attr = null;`. So, I think, you need to initialize your field somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

And where are you initializing `Attributes attr`?

You need to something like `Attributes attr = new Attributes();` because right know your variable does contain nothing - `null`

Comment: Question is not an answer!

Comment: @hotfix - actually the question points to the issue at hand: forgetting to initialise the `attr` variable.